# Getting This Error When Trying To Animate An ElevatedButton

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am currently trying to animate an elevatedButton, nothing too fancy just trying to animate the elevated property. So I’ve scaffolded a new flutter starter app in VS code and added in the relevant code for the animations and animation controller, however I keep getting this error : type ‘double’ is not a subtype of type ‘MaterialStateProperty<double?>?’ I don’t understand why, here’s my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation animation;

  @override void initState() {      
      super.initState();

      animationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
      );

      animation = Tween(begin: 50.0, end: 150.0).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(
          parent: animationController, 
          curve: Interval(0.0, 1.0, curve: Curves.easeInOut),
        ),
      );
  }

  @override void dispose() {
      animationController.dispose();

      super.dispose();
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                animationController.forward();
              }, 
              child: Text("Button Text"),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                elevation: animation.value,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: If you see any error with a stacktrace, please provide complete stacktrace here as well, it helps finding the issues pretty quickly. Anyways I have posted an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this with `MaterialStateProperty.all<double>(animation.value),` in button style

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation animation;

  @override void initState() {
    super.initState();

    animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
    );

    animation = Tween(begin: 50.0, end: 150.0).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animationController,
        curve: Interval(0.0, 1.0, curve: Curves.easeInOut),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                animationController.forward();
              },
              child: Text("Button Text"),
              style: ButtonStyle(
// here you will change the `MaterialStateProperty` value 
                elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all<double>(animation.value),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [`ButtonStyle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle-class.html) Documentation:

> Many of the ButtonStyle properties are `MaterialStateProperty` objects which resolve to different values depending on the button's state. For example the Color properties are defined with MaterialStateProperty and can resolve to different colors depending on if the button is pressed, hovered, focused, disabled, etc.

So what you need to do is Pass the `animation value` as a MaterialStateProperty.

In your case it would look like this:

```dart
style: ButtonStyle(  
  elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(animation.value), 
),
```

Check out the [`MaterialStateProperty`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialStateProperty-class.html) Class documentation to get more info.